# How to store the 'total' count of this polymorphic model in its associated models (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called *Vote* that has a polymorphic association with other two models: *Microposts* and *Comments*.

Here is their association:

**micropost.rb:**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

**comment.rb:**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :micropost, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :votes, :as => :votable, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

**vote.rb:**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The *Vote* model has a column called `polarity` (for voting up +1 and voting down -1).
I would like to add a `total` (the sum of the `polarity` of all the votes of a post or comment) to each instances of the Post and Comment model.

What's the best way of accomplishing this?

Example:

> Post (:id = 2)
>
> Vote (:polarity = 1) Vote (:polarity = -1) Vote (:polarity = 2)
>
> Post with ID 2 has a :total of 2 votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an instance method in `Post` and `Comment` models like:

```
def total
  self.votes.map {|v| v.polarity }.sum
end
```

Then put `@post.total` or `@comment.total`

Or you can create a helper which can do the same:

```
def total object
  object.votes.map {|v| v.polarity }.sum
end
```

Then put `<%= total @post %>` or `<%= total @comment %>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I will need something like this: `.order('total_votes DESC...` not sure if I can do that with a helper?

Comment: then make an instance method and sort by a virtual attribute `Post.order(&:total)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner. How do you build an instance method?

Comment: as i said, in your model `Post` or `Comment`